# Как составить ссылку из шаблона в php?

Tags: php

У меня есть строка

> " текст|https://site.ru "

Эта строка обрамлена пробелами, а посередине |

Как мне преобразовать такую строку в ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

как то так?

```
$a = preg_replace("/\s(.*?)\|(.*?)\s/", '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $string);
```

или лучше так:

```
[$txt, $href] = explode("|", trim($string));
$a = "<a href='$href'>$txt</a>"
```